# MySql 5.5; possible to exclude a table from logging?

Tags: mysql, logging

MySql 5.5 has a few logging option, among which the "Binary Logfile" with Binlog options which I do not want to use and the "query log file" which I want to use.

However, 1 program using 1 table in that database is filling this logfile with 50+Mb per day, so I would like that table to be excluded from this log.

Is that possible, or is the only way to install another MySql version and then to move this 1 table?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/change-replication-filter.html

Comment: its version is 5.5

Comment: You'll have to find a copy of the 5.5 documentation. That version is out of support, and the documentation has been taken down. The replication filter feature did exist in that version, if I recall, but the syntax may be different.

Comment: here is a copy :  https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/refman-5.5-en.a4.pdf

Comment: is that right? @BillKarwin

Comment: @BillKarwin, thank you, I did find the replication filter but I don't work with a replication server so I figured that was not for this case.

Comment: it's all in the mysql manuals files. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-archive.html

Comment: If you have no replication server, why are you keeping a binary log at all? For point in time recovery? If so, do you not need to recover the single table that you want to exclude?

Comment: Are you not expiring binary logs? 50MB per day doesn't seem like a great risk. Read about the server configuration option `expire_logs_days` in the manual.

Comment: I said I do not want to use the binlog. I only mentioned it to prevent people to answer that the binlog can exclude a table :-)

Comment: regardless, you should upgrade your mysql version to one that is supported, ideally the latest mysql or mariadb version available.  there are likely many unfixed security issues in your 5.5 version.

Comment: if you should upgrade your system to a more modern version. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/227464/upgrading-5-6-to-8-0-without-losing-any-data/227466

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are options for filtering the binlog by table, but not the query logs.

There are no options for filtering the general query log. It is either enabled for all queries, or else it's disabled.

There are options for filtering the slow query log, but not by table. For example, to log only queries that take longer than N seconds, or queries that don't use an index. Percona Server adds some options to filter the slow query log based on sampling.

You can use a session variable to disable either slow query or general query logging for queries run in a given session. This is a dynamic setting, so you can change it at will. But you would need to change your client code to do this every time you query that specific table.

Another option is to implement log rotation for the slow query log, so it never grows too large. See https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/04/18/rotating-mysql-slow-logs-safely/